# Find max value of X that satisfies both 9x < 10 && 7.5x < 8

Tags: math, dart

I am writing a program that needs to find the maximum value of X that satisfies the 2 following equations:

9x < 10
7.5x < 8

Can anyone advise on the best way to go about this? I am writing the program in Dart but would appreciate examples/advice in any language.

This is what I have done currently but I am not 100% sure this is correct:

```
double Xval = 10/9;
if(7.5 *  Xval > 8)
  Xval = 8 / 7.5;
```

Please note the program would have to work if we changed any or all of the numbers (e.g. the 9, 10, 7.5 or the 8).

Comment: How many digits after decimal points you want?

Comment: To 4 decimals is enough

Comment: Well tried, but your program will probably return the wrong answer 1., because of the integer division. (In C/C++ it will.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs some mathematical logic.

1)First find value of `x` by replacing `<` to `=`. Eg. Find `x` in `9x=10`.

2)Find minimum of both the solution `x`.

3)This minimum value will satisfy both the equation its obvious but we have replaced `<` with `=` so we need to subtract a smallest value by which we can find maximum `x` which satisfy the original equation.

4)So subtract the value `0.0001` from minimum if you want 4 decimal point precision. Generally subtract `(10)^(-DecimalPointPrecision)` value ,so here `DecimalPointPrecision` is equal to `4`.

5)This value you get will satisfy both the equation and it will be the maximum value of x.

I have written a code in java implementing this logic.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 class SolveEquation
 {
  public static void main(String [] args)
   {
        float ip1_left;
        float ip1_right;
        float ip2_left;
        float ip2_right;

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\nEnter the multiplier of x of 1st equation:");
        ip1_left=sc.nextFloat();

        System.out.print("Enter the constant of 1st equation:");
        ip1_right=sc.nextFloat();

        System.out.print("Enter the multiplier of x of 2nd equation:");
        ip2_left=sc.nextFloat();

        System.out.print("Enter the constant of x of 2nd equation:");
        ip2_right=sc.nextFloat();

        float ans1=ip1_right/ip1_left;
        float ans2=ip2_right/ip2_left;

        float min=ans1;

        if(ans2<ans1)
            min=ans2;
        //If you want 4 decimal precision then print 4 digits after point and subtract 0.0001 (where 1 is placed on 4th place after decimal point).
        System.out.printf("\nMaximum value of x is %.4f",min-0.0001); 



   }
 }
```

Sample output for input as per your question:
[image: Output]